# Delay() is not working outside of interrupt

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt

Delay() doesn't work inside ISR routines, but here I have used it in loop and outside interrupt section still Delay is not working, however there isn't any error coming. What is wrong?

```
int L = 2;
volatile int done0=0;                                //ISR variables
void recordL();                                              //ISR 1

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Start");

pinMode(L,INPUT);
}

void loop() {

interrupts(); 
attachInterrupt(0,recordL,RISING);
done0=0;

while(!done0)
{
    Serial.println(millis());
}
noInterrupts();

Serial.println("Detected");
delay(5000);
Serial.println("After Delay");
}

void recordL()
{
  Serial.println("in Interrupt0");
  done0=1;
}
```

Comment: What is it for ? Perhaps you don't need interrupts at all. Please don't use a Serial.println in the while-loop, the serial output buffer will get full. Please don't use Serial.println in the interrupt routine, because the Serial library uses interrupts itself. In most cases the attachInterrupt is done only once in the setup function.

Comment: Looks like I have made lot of mistakes. I need interrupt because I want to detect sound coming from 2nd IO pin. After attaching interrupt once in Setup, do I need to do interrupts() and nointerrupts() in Loop section?

Comment: I prefer to keep the interrupts running and use just variables for interrupt detection. The Arduino Uno can run a small interrupt routine a few thousand times per second. I don't understand the sound signal from a second I/O pin, can you explain that ?

Comment: Actually I have 3 sound sensors and sound can come at any time at these sensors (If sound is greater than some threshold then 1 else 0), so it can come simultaneously to all 3 with very small difference in time. I want to measure that exact time when sound has reached sensor. So I am using 2 interrupt pin and 1 simple pin which is waiting for sound in loop.

Comment: The trick with interrupts is to do the least possible amount of work. Just raise a flag or change a value and let the `loop` do the thing.

Comment: @LookAlterno That's why I have set 'done0' to 1. You also telling that?

Comment: Yes, LookAlterno is telling that. What kind of sound sensors? What kind of timing differences do you want to measure? Perhaps you need to timestamp the trigger moment. The Arduino Leonardo/(Pro)Micro has 5 interrupts. With the EnableInterrupt library, every pin of the Arduino Uno has an interrupt: https://github.com/GreyGnome/EnableInterrupt (although it is a little slower). You probably want to detect the first interrupt, and not the interrupts followed directly after that. Please tell us what your project is about before stepping into the XY-problem trap: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Jot thanks for your interest in project. My project is to identify direction of sound and make bot go in that direction with Obstacle avoidance. For deciding direction of sound I am using 3 sound sensors which uses Electret Microphones followed by amplifier and 'Time of Arrival' Principle. First I am doing it for 8 directions only (45 degree to each other). 2 sensors will decide zone horizontally and 3rd one will decide it is coming from front or back.

Comment: Is it completely silent and the sound a single loud clap ? Are the microphones 30 cm apart ? Then the delay is 900 µs. That might be possible, but not accurate. The interrupt software overhead is about 5 µs https://gammon.com.au/interrupts Can someone verify my calculations ? To detect someone speaking, you need a lot of processing power or perhaps a DSP and a Arduino can not do that.

Comment: I am using just a loud clap to make bot move, not voice of any person. Microphones are 15 cm apart. Yes your calculations are right, delay between sound arrival at different sensors won't be grater than 900 micro seconds if 30 cm apart.

Comment: I don't understand how you are measuring when the sound has reached three sensors with only one interrupt. Are you planning to use three interrupts?

Comment: I have arduino uno so I am using 2 interrupts and 1 sound sensor is waiting for sound in loop. Actually to simplify issue, I have asked question for just one interrupt. If you say I can share code for 3 sound sensors, however I am working on it, it's not complete yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
noInterrupts();

Serial.println("Detected");
delay(5000);
```

`delay()` won't work with interrupts turned off.

Comment: Ok. Is there need to off interrupt ? or detaching it?

Comment: If you don't want that interrupt while you are delaying and printing, detach the interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need interrupts() noInterrupts() in the loop section?

Yes, you do. Always.

The optimal workflow is

1. In the ISR itself, just raise a flag or directly change some global 
   variable.
2. In the `loop` you first copy that flag/variable to a local variable, using interrupts/noInterrupts to prevent the ISR changing the value while you are using/copying it.

Assignment are not atomic in Arduino World. That means that the value you are copying can change while you are doing it, and you end with garbage in your variables. Or, worse, it can change between one statement and the next. Try to debug that.

This is how you do it. In this example, I'm using an interrupt to manage a button (with debouncing). I need to detect state (pressed/not pressed) and timing (how long you pressed it). I can't directly use `lastFallingEdge` in `loop`; I copy it first so it won't change while I'm using it.

```
volatile unsigned long lastFallingEdge = 0; // For debouncing.
volatile boolean bPressed = false;

void buttonInterrupt(void)
{
    lastFallingEdge = millis();
    bPressed = true;
}

void loop()
{

    if(bPressed) {
        noInterrupts();
        bPressed = false;
        unsigned long falling = lastFallingEdge;
        interrupts();
        unsigned long len = millis() - falling;

        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: In other answer it is mentioned that Delay won't work after noInterrupts(). How to deal with that?

Comment: You put the delay() in loop(). You call the delay() after checking that an interrupt occurs.

Comment: There is the timestamp! Well done @LookAlterno. Perhaps the interrupt can stop updating the 'lastFallingEdge' while it has not been processed in the loop (while the flag is still true). Can the flag (byte) be reset after the interrupts are turned on ? (sorry for nitpicking).

Comment: Can the flag be ..? No. Look: 1) "loop()" calls "interrupts()", 2) An interrupt arrive, ISR is called, bPressed is set to true; 3) "loop()" execute "bPressed=false;". Now your system is in a inconsisten state (and you missed that button press). Interrupts are tricky; you have to keep it short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Delay() function works by using timer interrupts internally. If you disable all interrupts using NoInterrupt function , then how will it work. Using that function is not recommended in code, as it causes unexpected misbehaviors.

Comment: Yes got it. I am facing one more issue here, delay is not working when 2 ISR gets executed at same time (delay is in loop section), is that because there are only 2 interrupts in arduino and delay can't find free interrupt and so can't work?

Comment: Delay () in loop () doesn't work cz it comes after      nointerrupt() function

Comment: This is happening also after removing nointerrupt() (means after keeping interrupt always on).

Comment: Only attach interrupt is needed here....not needed in loop() ..only in setup()